# Same version of jq behaves differently on Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, jq

I have a bash script with JQ dependency (version jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe) and its running as desired on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS(bash version 4.4.19(1)-release), but it behaves differently on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (bash version 4.3.48(1)-release).

```
while read i;do
  echo ${i}
  echo "...."
  done<<<$(jq -c '.[]' <<<'[{"name" : "alpha"},{"name" : "beta"},{"name" : "gama"},{"name" : "delta"}]')
```

I am expecting every object to be printed on separate lines, just like the one below which i ran on Ubuntu 18,

```
{"name":"alpha"}
....
{"name":"beta"}
....
{"name":"gama"}
....
{"name":"delta"}
....
```

But on Ubuntu 16, I am getting this output,

```
{"name":"alpha"} {"name":"beta"} {"name":"gama"} {"name":"delta"}
....
```

When I try running the following script, it runs perfectly on both with every object on separate lines.
But as While loop is running in a subshell I can't preserve the state of the variable if any operation is done inside it. So this is not desired as I want to do some operation and preserve the stateof the variable.

```
jq -c '.[]' <<<'[{"name" : "alpha"},{"name" : "beta"},{"name" : "gama"},{"name" : "delta"}]' |while read i;do
    echo ${i}
    echo "...."
done
```

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything at finds before asking questions here; problems with inadequate quoting are explicitly included.

Comment: Also, if you just ran the `jq` without any `while read` loop you'd see identical output between the two versions, so you'd know that the problem is that bash has changed, not that jq has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated according to advice from @CharlesDuffy.

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  echo "..."
done <<< "$(jq -c '.[]' <<<'[{"name" : "alpha"},{"name" : "beta"},{"name" : "gama"},{"name" : "delta"}]')"
```

---

Original

This is related to **word splitting** in Bash. You have to add `""` explicitly to avoid word splitting.

```sh
while read i; do
  echo ${i}
  echo "...."
  done <<< "$(jq -c '.[]' <<<'[{"name" : "alpha"},{"name" : "beta"},{"name" : "gama"},{"name" : "delta"}]')"
```

[Bash changed here-string `<<<` splitting in 4.4 beta](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/CHANGES#L437)

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.4-beta, and
>   the previous version, bash-4.4-alpha.
>
> ...
>
> z.  Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation
>       has always said.

Comment: The "fixed" code could still use some work. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: why `echo ${i}` is broken (needs to be `echo "$i"`, or even better, `printf '%s\n' "$i"`); and see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best practices for using a `while read` loop (should be `while IFS= read -r i; do` to avoid munging backslashes or silently removing trailing whitespace).

Comment: Thanks @Simba , for here-string change information, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have a different script, this is just a dummy script to understand here-string behaviour. And btw thanks for telling about shellcheck.net its awesome